# Parsing JSON response from YouTube API using Swift

Tags: json, swift, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Below I've added the exact copy of the output I receive within the console when I request content detail from my Youtube channel.

The request is made using Alamofire but this is probably irrelevant. This is for iOS using Swift.

Using basic decoding I can get to the first level in the JSON, however I can't get my head around comprehensive JSON structures and how to break into ANY detail within the response.

```
    {
    etag = "7m_KKUulP0TshaC_TW0-pQ-UEJU";
    items =     (
                {
            contentDetails =             {
                relatedPlaylists =                 {
                    favorites = FL0VZ0PEkyUOmPbVJ1rRcdVg;
                    likes = LL0VZ0PEkyUOmPbVJ1rRcdVg;
                    uploads = UU0VZ0PEkyUOmPbVJ1rRcdVg;
                    watchHistory = HL;
                    watchLater = WL;
                };
            };
            etag = "QT41YKfmkOf65gBK7Fg_nqflh9Y";
            id = UC0VZ0PEkyUOmPbVJ1rRcdVg;
            kind = "youtube#channel";
            snippet =             {
                description = "";
                localized =                 {
                    description = "";
                    title = "James Faulkner";
                };
                publishedAt = "2017-09-27T20:56:20Z";
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        height = 88;
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzLxbetHiMHm4ssQvI0zF1aAiM29r1ulQKEUw=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo";
                        width = 88;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 800;
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzLxbetHiMHm4ssQvI0zF1aAiM29r1ulQKEUw=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo";
                        width = 800;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 240;
                        url = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzLxbetHiMHm4ssQvI0zF1aAiM29r1ulQKEUw=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo";
                        width = 240;
                    };
                };
                title = "James Faulkner";
            };
            statistics =             {
                commentCount = 0;
                hiddenSubscriberCount = 0;
                subscriberCount = 0;
                videoCount = 2;
                viewCount = 96;
            };
        }
    );
    kind = "youtube#channelListResponse";
    pageInfo =     {
        resultsPerPage = 1;
        totalResults = 1;
    };
}
```

Could anyone help me start to break into this JSON, lets say to URL of the High Thumbnail?

Comment: Please provide valid json

Comment: Well this is the direct extract, when I put it is a “beautifier” to clear it up, I get the same reply. That is it not valid. However I don’t get why it would be invalid.

Comment: You can autogenerate Codable struct with https://app.quicktype.io?share=FmQcxvgKHRcSzxyY7mAk but you need valid JSON

Comment: That's already a JSON transformed with (NS)JSONSerialization into NSDictionary/NSArray/NSString. Copy/paste what you gave in a JSONValidator (there are plenty onlines), you'll see... It's `PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.openStep`/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console output is the object print. if you like to see the JSON format output in console of response data, use the following code:

```
if let JSONString = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
       print(JSONString)
   }
```

Try with the model classes to decode your response data from Alamofire as below

Models

```
struct YouTubeModel: Codable {
    let kind, etag: String?
    let pageInfo: PageInfo?
    let items: [Item]
}
struct Item: Codable {
    let kind, etag, id: String?
    let snippet: Snippet?
    let contentDetails: ContentDetails?
}

struct ContentDetails: Codable {
    let relatedPlaylists: RelatedPlaylists?
}

struct RelatedPlaylists: Codable {
    let likes, favorites, uploads, watchHistory: String?
    let watchLater: String?
}

struct Snippet: Codable {
    let title, snippetDescription: String?
    let publishedAt: String?
    let thumbnails: Thumbnails?
    let localized: Localized?
    let country: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case snippetDescription = "description"
        case publishedAt, thumbnails, localized, country
    }
}

struct Localized: Codable {
    let title, localizedDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case localizedDescription = "description"
    }
}

struct Thumbnails: Codable {
    let thumbnailsDefault, medium, high: Default

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case thumbnailsDefault = "default"
        case medium, high
    }
}

struct Default: Codable {
    let url: String
    let width, height: Int
   }

struct PageInfo: Codable {
    let totalResults, resultsPerPage: Int?
}
```

Inside your Almofire response method where you print responseData object in your post:

```
let youTubeModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(YouTubeModel.self, from: responseData)
print(youTubeModel.items[0].snippet?.thumbnails?.high.url )
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, thanks very much. I had it set at responseJSON which slightly threw me for a while but the use of CodingKeys etc has been somewhat limited. So this has really helped me. Thanks again.